# Linux Date not showing the date value sometimes

Tags: linux, date, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have defined a variable inside one of the shell script to create the file name with date value in it.

I used "date +%Y%m%d" command to insert the current date which was defined in date_val variable.

And I have defined the filename variable to have "${path}/sample_${date_val}.txt

For few days it was creating the file name properly as ***/programfiles/sample_20180308.txt***

But today the filename was created without date as ***/programfiles/sample_.txt***

When I try to execute the command "date +%Y%m%d" in linux, it is returning the correct value - 20180309.

Any idea why the filename was created without the date value ??? . I did not modify anything in my script too. So wondering what might have gone wrong.

Sample excerpt of my script is given below for easy understanding :

**EDITED**

```
path=/programfiles
date_val=$(date +%Y%m%d )
file_name=${path}/sample_${date_val}.txt
```

Comment: In order to determine what went wrong, we need more information. May we see an excerpt of the script(s) where you set the date_val and filename variables? Until then, here's a wild guess. On Linux, the "date" program is usually in your executable search PATH. Because you use $path, it is possible that something in your script mistakenly changed the PATH variable, which could then make the "date" program not found, hence not executed.

Comment: How many `//` are you trying to put between `${path}` and `sample_${date_val}.txt` ?? You have `path=/programfiles/` (which includes a trailing `'/'`) and a `'/'` again between `${path}/sample_...`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin My apologies. It's a typo. now i rectified

Comment: @JKC, OK, in that case, then there is nothing disclosed in the 3-lines you have posted that explain the empty date. You hardcode `path=/programfiles` which effectively makes `file_name=/programfiles/sample_$(date +%Y%m%d).txt`. There is nothing in that assignment, in and of itself, that would lead to an empty date. (though you should double-quote your strings, there is no chance of an intervening whitespace in the lines provided). Please post [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help further.

Comment: Hi @DavidC.Rankin . This is the only commands that I have in my script. Nothing else

Comment: You are on Linux right? (not WSL)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes I am using Linux only

Answer (score 1):

Although incredibly unlikely, it's certainly *possible* for `date` to fail, based on the source code. Under the covers, it calls either `clock_gettime()` or `gettimeofday()`, both of which can fail.

The `date` program will also refuse to output anything to standard output if the date from either of those two functions is out of range during the call to (which is possible *if* they fail).

It's also possible that the `date` program could "disappear" for various reasons, such as actually being hidden or permissions changed, or a shortage of resources like file handles when attempting to open the executable.

As mentioned, all these possibilities are a stretch, unlikely to happen in the real world.

If you want to handle the case where you get inadequate output from `date`, you can simply try until you get a valid one, something like (with the possibility of adding some limit to detect if it's *never* any good):

```
todaysDate="$(date +%Y%m%d)"
while [[ ! $x =~ ^[0-9]{8}$ ]] ; do
    sleep 1
    todaysDate="$(date +%Y%m%d)"
done
# todaysDate now guaranteed to be eight digits.
```

Comment: Well qualified "*incredibly unlikely*", though given the content of the question, that is as likely as anything else.